# Magento: Convert Quote to Order

Tags: magento

What would be the steps involved in converting a quote object in magento to an order.

Say i have the following:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(100);
```

There is no order yet and this quote object is still active.

How do I go from here to completing that quote and making an order from it.

I have tried:

```
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
```

This creates an order but doesnt complete the quote. Also, the order is in a pending status and not processing i.e. it has not been invoiced.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried the `Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Quote` - `toOrder` method?

```php
    /**
     * Convert quote model to order model
     *
     * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote
     * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Order
     */
    public function toOrder(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote, $order=null)
```

Example:

```php
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load(100);
$order = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote')->toOrder($quote);
```

Comment: specifically:$convertQuote = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
        $order = $convertQuote->toOrder($quote);

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I tried `var_dump($order->getIncrementId());` at the end of the script, which prints out the increment ID just fine but when I check in the DB there's no record in sales_flat_order with that increment ID

Edit: figured it out - need to add `$order->save()` to the end